# JPA/Hibernate - identifier of an instance of x was altered exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a JPA/Hibernate object which uses a composite key as the primary key. I am trying to read the object from the database and make an update.

Lets say the primary key is (id and name) and the following rows exist in the database.

```
1   john   London
2   bob    Birmingham
3   Dave   Kent
```

If i load an object using the key (1,john) then everything works fine. If i load it using the same primary but with a difference case using (1, John) then i get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Document was altered from com.myPck.test1.documentsPK[ Id=1, msgOwner=john ] to com.myPck.test1.documentsPK[ Id=1, msgOwner=John ];
```

After i load the row i do update it using JPQL but i dont update any of the primary key columns. Interestingly if i search for a row that does not exist i dont get that exception. It only occurs if i search for a row that does exist but the case used on the key is different from what is actually in the database.

What could be causing this and how do i resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: mysql? (some more characters, just ignore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the code for the Compound Key class that you are using. My guess is that you have a badly implemented equals and hashCode method on the compound primary key class.

Comment: Thanks - You were right. The problem was related to the login in the quals method. The method equals() was used to compare a string instead of equalsIgnoreCase().